# How to update all records with a NULL value to the next existing value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This might be SQL 101, but it's stumping me.

I have data like this:

```
ID     ZipCode     Value
1      12345       1
2      12346       Null
3      12347       Null
4      12348       2
5      12349       3
6      12350       Null
7      12351       Null
8      12352       4
```

I need a way to update records that have a null 'value' is updated to the NEXT available value.

ie:

```
ID     ZipCode     Value
1      12345       1
2      12346       2
3      12347       2
4      12348       2
5      12349       3
6      12350       4
7      12351       4
8      12352       4
```

I think this can be done easily enough with a cursor, but there has to be a better way.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Comment: I found some things on google about "sql find missing date ranges" that might be relevant....

Comment: Also please specify the SQL dialect, preferably including the relevant tag as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**There is no need to use cursor.**
Updating the table in a single statement can be tricky.

So for safety I would first get the result set with the values to assign for all `NULL` values:

```
WITH B AS
(
SELECT ID, (SELECT MIN(Value) 
            FROM MyTable 
            WHERE ID > A.ID AND MyTable.Value IS NOT NULL) ValueToAssign
FROM MyTable A
WHERE Value IS NULL
)


UPDATE MyTable
SET Value = B.ValueToAssign
FROM MyTable JOIN B ON MyTable.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: That does update the null records, but it updates them all to the highest available 'Value' (4) in this case, not the next available value. I'm using MS SQL Server 2008. Not R2

Comment: Perfect! Exactly What I was looking for. I will do some serious analysis of your code.

Comment: This works with the assumption that the values in `Value` column are ascending in the same order as `ID` values.

Comment: @ypercube - you have to assume some ordering, this is the ordering the OP supplied..

Answer (score 0):

It works if there are gaps between ID.

Here's a Demo on [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cddb7/2/0).

```
;with cte
as
(
select ID, ZipCode, Value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) rn
from tb o
)
, ct
as
(
select top 1 * 
from cte  
order by rn desc

union all

select t.ID, t.ZipCode, 
case when t.Value is null then o.Value else t.Value end 'Value', t.rn
from cte t inner join ct o on t.rn = o.rn - 1
)

update tb
set Value = ct.Value
from tb inner join ct on tb.ID = ct.ID
where tb.Value is null
```